# What kind of quotation marks does `bundle install --binstubs` want?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a Ruby project that I didn't write but am responsible for maintaining. As recommended, the files generated by `bundle install --binstubs` are checked into version control.

It seems that, depending on which local environment I'm using, regenerating the binstubs changes the scripts from single-quotes to double-quotes (or vice-versa). Which of course makes git think I made local changes. I'm guessing this is some gem version difference thing but don't really know where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Bundler [switched the world to double quotes](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/a77ca278809d7f31fa51e4b821faed86324c8275) and are enforcing it with Rubocop going forward. If you upgrade (or downgrade, but why?) bundler so that every environment has the same version, the bad behavior should stop.